# Weka not display Correctly classified instances as output

Tags: weka

I am new on weka. I have a dataset in csv with 5000 samples. here 20 samples of it; when I upload this dataset into weka, it looks ok, but when I run knn algorithm it gives a result that is not supposed to give. here is the sample data.

a,b,c,d

74,85,123,1

73,84,122,1

72,83,121,1

70,81,119,1

70,81,119,1

69,80,118,1

70,81,119,1

70,81,119,1

76,87,125,1

76,87,125,1

82,92,146,2

74,86,140,2

68,80,134,2

64,76,130,2

64,75,132,2

83,96,152,2

72,85,141,2

71,83,141,2

69,81,139,2

65,79,137,2

here is the result :

=== Cross-validation ===
=== Summary ===

Correlation coefficient                  0.6148
Mean absolute error                      0.2442
Root mean squared error                  0.4004
Relative absolute error                 50.2313 %
Root relative squared error             81.2078 %
Total Number of Instances             5000

it is supposed to give this kind of result like:
Correctly classified instances: 69 92%
Incorrectly classified instances: 6 8%

What should be the problem? What am I missing? I did this in all other algorithms but they all give the same output. I have used sample weka datasets, they all work as expected.

Comment: What is the exact name (and settings) of the classifier you are trying to use? If you're using the Weka Explorer interface, what does it say next to the **Choose** button at the top of the **Classify** tab?

Comment: @nekomatic hi, thanks for your comment. it says IKB. I am trying to apply knn algorithm

Comment: I assume you mean IBk. OK, so have you selected which attribute is the class attribute, from the dropdown above the **Start** button on that tab?

Comment: @nekomatic the last one, the d.

Comment: Please read [Under what circumstances may I add “urgent” or other similar phrases to my question, in order to obtain faster answers?](//meta.stackoverflow.com/q/326569) - the summary is that this is not an ideal way to address volunteers, and is probably counterproductive to obtaining answers. Please refrain from adding this to your questions.

Comment: @halfer you are right, thanks a lot

Comment: Thanks. Additionally, if you are composing your questions on a mobile phone (and so cannot easily produce capital letters), it may be better to use a PC or laptop. Volunteer editors are happy to help out, but they are not your auto-correct - they have enough work to do as it is.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The **IBk** algorithm can be used for *regression* (predicting the value of a numeric response for each instance) as well as for *classification* (predicting which class each instance belongs to).

It looks like all the values of the class attribute in your dataset (column `d` in your CSV) are numbers. When you load this data into Weka, Weka therefore guesses that this attribute should be treated as a numeric one, not a nominal one. You can tell this has happened because the histogram in the Preprocess tab looks something like this:

[image: uncoloured histogram]

instead of like this (coloured by class):

[image: histogram coloured by class]

The result you're seeing when you run IBk is the result of a regression fit (predicting a numeric value of column d for each instance) instead of a classification (selecting the most likely nominal value of column d for each instance).

To get the result you want, you need to tell Weka to treat this attribute as nominal. When you load the csv file in the Preprocess tab, check `Invoke options dialog` in the file dialog window. Then when you click **Open**, you'll get this window:

[image: Weka csv options dialog]

The field `nominalAttributes` is where you can give Weka a list of which attributes are nominal ones even if they look numeric. Entering `4` here will specify that the fourth attribute (column) in the input is a nominal attribute. Now IBk should behave as you expect.

You could also do this by applying the **NumericToNominal** unsupervised attribute filter to the already loaded data, again specifying attribute 4 otherwise the filter will apply to all the attributes.

The ARFF format used for the Weka sample datasets includes a specification of which attributes are which type. After you've imported (or filtered) your dataset as above, you can save it as ARFF and you'll then be able to reload it without having to go through the same process.

Comment: You are the hero my friend. :)   I couldnt mange the filter  and the invoke options dialog way, but the logic behind it %100 correct. I have changed the dataset's last attribute to yes/no then it worked flawlessly. I really appriciate for your time, help, and this  wonderfully explained answer. I hope this will help other people... Thnaks a lot.

Comment: Glad to know it helped. A really good way to get started with Weka and data mining, if you have some time, is to take the online courses at https://weka.waikato.ac.nz/explorer

Comment: You save my day!